# Exception handling in Erlang to Continue execution

Tags: error-handling, exception, erlang, ejabberd

What I am trying to do is `mochijson2:decode(Ccode)` generates any exception or error, program execution should not stop and case branch {error, Reason} should get executed.

But when I am trying to get it implemented, it generates error at first line while checking and code doesn't continue execution for lines below it.

```
SCustomid = case mochijson2:decode(Ccode) of
  {struct, JsonDataa} -> 
       {struct, JsonData} = mochijson2:decode(Ccode),
       Mvalll = proplists:get_value(<<"customid">>, JsonData),
       Pcustomid = erlang:binary_to_list(Mvalll),
       "'" ++ Pcustomid ++ "'";
  {error, Reason} -> escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid)


end,
```

You could suggest if I need to use Try Catch. I am a bit experienced with Ejabberd but newbie for Erlang. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the reason is an exception happens in mochijson2:decode/1. The function doesn't return a error as a tuple, instead the process crashes. There isn't enough information to tell what exactly the reason is. However I guess that the data format of `Ccode` might be wrong. You can handle exception using `try ... catch` statement:

```
SCustomid = try
  case mochijson2:decode(Ccode) of
    {struct, JsonDataa} -> 
       {struct, JsonData} = mochijson2:decode(Ccode),
       Mvalll = proplists:get_value(<<"customid">>, JsonData),
       Pcustomid = erlang:binary_to_list(Mvalll),
       "'" ++ Pcustomid ++ "'";
    {error, Reason} -> 
       escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid) 
  end   
catch
  What:Reason ->
    escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid)
end,
```

Or just `catch`:

```
SCustomid = case catch(mochijson2:decode(Ccode)) of
  {struct, JsonDataa} -> 
       {struct, JsonData} = mochijson2:decode(Ccode),
       Mvalll = proplists:get_value(<<"customid">>, JsonData),
       Pcustomid = erlang:binary_to_list(Mvalll),
       "'" ++ Pcustomid ++ "'";
  {error, Reason} -> 
     escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid);
  {What, Reason} ->
    escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid)
end,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
    SCustomid = try
                    {struct, JsonData} = mochijson2:decode(Ccode),
                    Mvalll = proplists:get_value(<<"customid">>, JsonData),
                    Pcustomid = erlang:binary_to_list(Mvalll),
                    "'" ++ Pcustomid ++ "'"
                catch _:_ -> escape_str(LServer, Msg#archive_message.customid)
                end
```